# OAuth support for user authentication for ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd

Is there any way to use OAuth API for some social webservice like facebook, for authenticating users for ejabberd?? One thing(but not feasible) we can do is that after facebook authenticates the user, then only xmpp connection to ejabberd should occur (with ejabberd external_auth module enabled to just bypass the authentication), but then how will ejabberd maintain that user information, for exchanging messaging/presence info with his/her friends, as it would only be getting access_token from facebook instead of username/password??

Any feasible approach??

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I'll be glad to know.

Comment: We can treat the fb access_token as ejabberd user password. For this, as soon as you get the access_token from fb, just update user's password in the ejabberd database using php. In this way user's password in ejabberd changes with every fb authentication, which is good from security perspective. I know this is just a workaround, rather than being a perfect solution. I didn't come across any better solution than this yet.

Comment: Didn't you think of writing a plugin with Erlang that goes and check directly from Facebook, this is much better than getting the access token using a third party script and storing it ejabberd's DB. Do I make sense of what I say?

Comment: That will do, but that would require learning Erlang programming, to which I am new. If you know Erlang, you can try that.